# Stress 3D Surface Plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I wrote a finite element program in Matlab which calculates the stresses of a 3D plate.
Now I would like to print these stresses but it is really hard to do for me. For each gauss point I can have the XYZ associated coordinate with its stress.
How can I do a plot like the ones I see in the FE software in Matlab? Currently what I can do is to plot a colour for the XYZ point assigning a colour range to the stresses. My result is a scatter plot.
I would like to have something like this
[image]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Matlab has a [`surf(X, Y, Z, C)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) function that can take a color argument (`C`). Without the `C` argument, it uses the `Z` value to color the surface.

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:0.5:10,1:20);
Z = sin(X) + cos(Y);
C = X.*Y;
surf(X,Y,Z,C)
```

The color is set using your active colormap.

If you want more control over the colors,
`C` can also be a `MxNx3` array where the `C(M, N, :)` gives the RGB value of the color at the `MxN`th point.